# Commands with Variables in ROOT

Tags: c++, root-framework

I am trying to create a simple loop that calls data from sequential channels. I have channels numbered 1-8 (named qL1 - qL8) and need to call the `qL*->Draw();` command for all of them.

Is there a way to use a loop to continually update the number in the command? I believe the equivalent code in a c shell would be:

```
for {set i 1} {$i <= 8} {incr i} {
    qL$i->Draw();
}
```

As stated in the title, I am trying to write a macro for ROOT. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## put everything into an array/vector

well, you can fill your channels (I assume `TH1` here, but it should work similarly for `TGraph`, `TTree`, etc) into an array/vector first, since they are pointers anyhow:

```
TH1* qL[9];  // nine elements to have indices matching
qL[1] = qL1;
qL[2] = qL2;
qL[3] = qL3;
qL[4] = qL4;
qL[5] = qL5;
qL[6] = qL6;
qL[7] = qL7;
qL[8] = qL8;

for (int i = 1 ; i <= 8 ; i++) { qL[i]->Draw() ; }
```

though that probably doesn't gain you much.

## use ROOT's directory mechanism and use string manipulation

What might be better suited is to work with root's directory management (if you anyhow get your channels from an input file, that should be a straight forward solution):

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 8 ; i++) {
    TH1* localhist = (TH1*) gDirectory->Get(Form("qL%d",i));
    localhist->Draw();
}
```

Here, `Form(...)` is a cstring and the syntax for `Form` is the same as for `printf` (google is your friend). And `Get` looks for an object of which the *name* is the cstring provided. (be aware of the room for confusion in `TH1* variablename = new TH1F( NAME, TITLE , ...)`, what matters is the `NAME` and not the `variablename`)

## preprocessor macros

you can use a preprocessor (e.g. boost) to concatenate the string part (qL) of your variable with a number and use this in a preprocessor macro which takes the number as argument.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>
#define qL(i) BOOST_PP_CAT(qL, i)


TH1* qL1 = new TH1F("test","test",1,0,1);
qL(1)->GetName();
```

The problem with this is, that the argument must be known at compile time, if you put this in a for loop, you'll get errors because `qLi` is not known.
Which can be done in preprocessor, though not sure if this will greatly work out on the long run

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp>
#define HHHHH(z,n,zz) BOOST_PP_CAT(qL, n) zz
BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO(1,3,HHHHH,->Draw();)
```

Answer (score 0):

No. If only your channels names were an array, e.g. `qL[N]`, where `N=0, 1, ..., 7`, that would be possible with something like

```
for (Int_t i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    qL[i]->Draw();
}
```